# How do I save the current logged in username in the CreateView submit action in Django?

Tags: python, django, generics, view

I want to create a restaurant review submission page where the username of the user who is submitting the review is saved in the database table. I think I have to override the save method of the CreateView but I don't know how.

Here is what I have till now.

## views.py

```
class WriteReview(CreateView):
    model = Review
    success_url = reverse_lazy('restaurant_list')
    fields = ['restaurant','review']
```

## models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')
    review = models.TextField()
    user = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s review: %s..." % (self.restaurant, self.review[:20])
```

Comment: I solved it by making a custom form_valid method. Here's the code:
def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(WriteReview, self).form_valid(form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my class to add a custom method to it like the following.

```
class WriteReview(CreateView):
    model = Review
    success_url = reverse_lazy('restaurant_list')
    fields = ['restaurant','review']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(WriteReview, self).form_valid(form)
```

That did the trick! :)

Answer (score 2):

As you say your answer works but it would make much more sense to write your model like this (code assumes you have already imported the `User` model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')
    review = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now the table is actually related to the `User` one, so changes in a user's detail's will propagate to the `Review` model. You can also then take advantage of convenient shortcuts like dot notation to access `User` attributes from `Review` instances, or to see all any user instance, we'll call ours `u`, reviews with `u.review_set.all()`. You would still set the user to the one submitting the form in the `form_valid` method like so:

```
class WriteReview(CreateView):
...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Glad you brought it up cause I was trying to find an answer. However, I want to create the ForeignKey relation while I'm using the generic CreateView. Is that possible with your code? Or do I have to tinker with my view class too?

Comment: I was wondering, when there is a ForeignKey relation, doesn't Django save the id of the User instead of the username itself? So if I stick to my original code but change the first line of the form_valid method to this:  form.instance.user = self.request.user.id, will it not work?

Comment: I've never done it that way and I'm not on my dev machine to check just now but try it and see, I can't see any harm in it.

Comment: It works. I had to recreate the database though cause somehow it had problems migrating.

Comment: Also, you don't have to save the user id.. just save the user, it automatically converts to the user id as it is stated in the model to ForeignKey the User model. Basically the above line didn't work, but this----> form.instance.user = self.request.user did work! Hmmm. A lot to learn still. :)